# Override prefix in Spring Boot's RedisProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm trying to work with multiple Redis instances in my app. Eventually I came to specifying different prefixed Redis properties in my `application.properties` and having `OneRedisConfig` and `TwoRedisConfig` classes with a number of required fields:

**application.properties**

```
one.redis.host=localhost
one.redis.port=6379

two.redis.host=localhost
two.redis.port=6380
```

**OneRedisConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "one.redis" )
public class OneRedisConfig {
  private String host;
  private int port;

  // getters and setters
}
```

The problem is I have to specify *all* the required configuration properties in my `OneRedisConfig` class, which is a duplication of what is already in   `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties` class. For example, if I need to configure the pool settings, too, I'll have to put a static class `Pool` into `OneRedisConfig` with fields like `maxIdle`, `minIdle` etc. 
Is it possible to avoid this duplication and also allow to specify *any* additional configuration property in my `application.properties` with a corresponding prefix, so that it is automatically picked up by my custom config class? 
I assumed it should be possible by simply overriding: `OneRedisConfig extends RedisProperties`, but this gave me an error on startup:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConnectionConfiguration
>   required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>     - oneRedisConfig: defined in file [/my/package/config/OneRedisConfig.class]
>     - spring.redis-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties:
>   defined in null

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @apines, I just used [PropertyResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html) and manual calls to things like `propertyResolver.getProperty( "redis1.host" )`. So there's no automatic mapping in my case, effectively.